# Setting video /audio buffer time in DirectShow

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I have a source filter (rtsp source filter). I can set its video/audio buffer time in graph edit.
But do not know programatically how to set.

Does any body know a generic mechanishm which i can set a buffer time for an (live) source filter?

Best Wishes

Comment: Which Rtsp source filter are you using?

Comment: I am experimenting with the RtspSource filter at http://www.rtpstream.com/downloads.shtml

Comment: But many source filters has this kind of buffer time i think. I can not see any COM interface which i can set it.

Answer (score 0):

if you save the .grf file it saves settings I believe.
[DirectShow - passing parameters to custom source push filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142739/directshow-passing-parameters-to-custom-source-push-filter) might help